# Detect touch on transformed shapelayer

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I am having trouble detecting touch on shape layers that have been transformed.

Touch is ignoring the transformation and detecting the layer in the wrong position.

**Steps to reproduce:**

I create a custom view where I override the draw: method to create a number of paths on shapes layers.

The shape layers are **transformed** to a new position and size in the view.

When I try to detect if a shape layer has been touched, the detection is in the wrong location.

Looking at the screenshot below, the red shape layer is what is drawn in the view.

The outlined shape is the original untransformed shape (this is not drawn in the view).

[image]

When I touch the red shape layer, nothing is detected.

If touch the screen where the original shape would be without any transformations, the shape layer is detected!

This means the shape layer is being detected on a blank part of the screen.

**Code to reproduce:**

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomView: UIView {

    let bezierPaths: [UIBezierPath] = MyShapes.headShape()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        //draw each bezierPath onto its own shape layer
        for bezierPath in bezierPaths {

            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

            shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
            shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath

            //transform shape to new size and position in view
            let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 100, y: 100)
            let affineTransform = scale.concatenating(transform)
            shapeLayer.setAffineTransform(affineTransform)

            //add the shape layer to the view
            self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        }

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

            for sublayer in self.layer.sublayers! {

                if let shapeLayer = sublayer as? CAShapeLayer {
                    if shapeLayer.path!.contains(touchLocation) {

                        print("touched the shape layer")

                    }
                }

            }

        }        

    }

}


class MyShapes {

    static func headShape() -> [UIBezierPath] {

        var paths = [UIBezierPath]()

        let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 285, height: 508)

        //create shape and add to array
        let head_FrontPath = UIBezierPath()
        head_FrontPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 164.47, y: frame.minY + 34.31))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 165.1, y: frame.minY + 28.52), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 164.76, y: frame.minY + 32.42), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 165, y: frame.minY + 30.44))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 161.97, y: frame.minY + 12.86), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 165.42, y: frame.minY + 22.25), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 163.22, y: frame.minY + 15.36))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 149.75, y: frame.minY + 0.95), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 160.72, y: frame.minY + 10.35), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 155.7, y: frame.minY + 3.15))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 142.5, y: frame.minY + 0.1), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 146.73, y: frame.minY - 0.16), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 144.37, y: frame.minY + 0.1))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 135.25, y: frame.minY + 0.95), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 140.63, y: frame.minY + 0.1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 138.28, y: frame.minY - 0.16))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 123.03, y: frame.minY + 12.86), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 129.3, y: frame.minY + 3.15), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 124.29, y: frame.minY + 10.35))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 119.9, y: frame.minY + 28.52), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 121.78, y: frame.minY + 15.36), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 119.59, y: frame.minY + 22.25))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 120.6, y: frame.minY + 34.76), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 120, y: frame.minY + 30.59), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 120.28, y: frame.minY + 32.73))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 117.33, y: frame.minY + 37.38), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 119.21, y: frame.minY + 35.05), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 116.96, y: frame.minY + 36.32))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 122.02, y: frame.minY + 48.93), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 117.83, y: frame.minY + 38.83), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 120.95, y: frame.minY + 50.57))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 122.31, y: frame.minY + 47.94), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 122.15, y: frame.minY + 48.73), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 122.25, y: frame.minY + 48.39))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 124.28, y: frame.minY + 58.91), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 122.66, y: frame.minY + 51.97), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 123.39, y: frame.minY + 57.57))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 134.31, y: frame.minY + 64.55), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 125.54, y: frame.minY + 60.79), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 132.74, y: frame.minY + 64.24))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 142.23, y: frame.minY + 66.38), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 135.73, y: frame.minY + 64.83), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 140.24, y: frame.minY + 66.14))
        head_FrontPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 142.23, y: frame.minY + 66.43))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 142.5, y: frame.minY + 66.4), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 142.3, y: frame.minY + 66.43), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 142.41, y: frame.minY + 66.41))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 142.77, y: frame.minY + 66.43), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 142.58, y: frame.minY + 66.41), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 142.7, y: frame.minY + 66.43))
        head_FrontPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 142.77, y: frame.minY + 66.38))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 150.69, y: frame.minY + 64.55), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 144.75, y: frame.minY + 66.14), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 149.27, y: frame.minY + 64.83))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 160.71, y: frame.minY + 58.91), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 152.26, y: frame.minY + 64.23), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 159.46, y: frame.minY + 60.79))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 162.71, y: frame.minY + 47.63), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 161.63, y: frame.minY + 57.54), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 162.37, y: frame.minY + 51.68))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 162.97, y: frame.minY + 48.46), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 162.77, y: frame.minY + 48), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 162.86, y: frame.minY + 48.29))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 167.67, y: frame.minY + 36.91), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 164.05, y: frame.minY + 50.1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 167.16, y: frame.minY + 38.36))
        head_FrontPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 164.47, y: frame.minY + 34.31), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 168.03, y: frame.minY + 35.87), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 165.87, y: frame.minY + 34.63))
        head_FrontPath.close()
        paths.append(head_FrontPath)

        //create a number of other shapes
        //...
        //...
        //...

        //return array of shapes
        return paths
    }

}
```

How can I detect the **transformed** shape in the correct position on the screen using touch?

Comment: IIRC from my math lessons, you have to apply the inverted affine transform of your layer to your `touchLocation` before testing it.

Comment: Yes you are correct. It worked once inverted. Thanks so much.

Comment: Please can you post as answer. This did the trick: let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self).applying(affineTransform.inverted())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the inverted affine transform of your layer to your `touchLocation` before testing it:

```
let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self).applying(affineTransform.inverted())
```